# Django M2M with addititional data with through

Tags: python, django, m2m

My problem is as follows.  I am saving data for patients from a form on a webpage.  The form is generated from model definitions in models.py.  The information that I save is name, surname amongst others.  I have a field for diagnosis which is selected using a multichoiceField and I save it using manytomany.
When the data is saved, a separate table is created for the diagnosis assigned to each patient as expected.  The table contains a diagnosis and the ID of the patient it applies to.  Each diagnosis is saved as a separate record.
In addition to selecting the diagnosis, I also save the date that the diagnosis is made.  You will see what I mean in the models.py and form.py code below.
I would like to have the date for which the diagnosis was made also saved in the table but I can't figure out how to do this.  I have tried following the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany as well as some other posts on SO, but cannot figure out how to do it.  I can't figure out how the views, forms and models need to be set up in order to achieve.  Is it possible to do this and if so how?  I have tried using an intermediate model with manytomany and 'through', but I do not understand it.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Below is a simplified version of my code:

models.py:

```
class diagnosisChoices(models.Model):  #This represents the list in the drop down menu for the different diagnosis.
    diagnosis = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    def __str__(self):              
        return self.diagnosis

class PatientData(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    dateOfBirth = models.DateField(default = datetime.datetime.now())
    diagnosis = models.ManyToManyField(
        'diagnosisChoices',
        #on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

views.py:

```
 def patientDataView(request):
    uId = request.user.id 

    if request.method == "POST":
    form = PatientDataForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
        model_instance.timestamp = timezone.now()
        model_instance.save()
        #model_instance.add(uId)
        form.save_m2m()          
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/dataBase')

    else:

    form = PatientDataForm()

    return render(request, "dataBaseTest.html", {'form': form})
    date_of_diagnosis = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from .models import PatientData
from .models import diagnosisChoices #This is the list of diagnosis in the dropdown
from django.forms import extras
import datetime

from functools import partial
class PatientDataForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        thisYear = now.year
        DateInput = partial(forms.DateInput, {'class': 'datepicker'})
        widgets = {
        }

        model = PatientData
        fields = ['Name', 
                'Surname',
                'dateOfBirth',
                'diagnosis',
                'date_of_diagnosis',
                ]
```

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

The main thing that you are not getting is on the models.py, so I will focus on it.

You need three tables to do what you have described: `diagnosisData`, `PatientData` and a 'membership' table which I call `diagnosisPatient`. Then you build your model like this:

```
class diagnosisChoices(models.Model):
    diagnosis = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class PatientData(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dateOfBirth = models.DateField(default = datetime.datetime.now())
    diagnosis = models.ManyToManyField('diagnosisChoices',through='diagnosisPatient')

class diagnosisPatient(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey('PatientData')
    diagnosis = models.ForeignKey('diagnosisChoices') 
    dateOfDiagnosis = models.DateField()
```

Once you have your model built this way, you should save your `PatientData` and your `diagnosisChoices` instances as usual. FOr the many to many relation, you should save it manualy on the `diagnosisPatient` table using the apropriate foreign keys and date. You can query the many to many relation from the `PatientData` model as usual with `objects.all()` function.

The thing here to keep in mind is that ManyToMany relations in django are always creating a new membership table for you behind the scenes. So when you do not need to insert extra information on the relationship the `diagnosisPatient` table is just made of two foreign keys, and it is hidden. The through argument on this relationship is just bringing this table to light and giving you control back to put whatever new relationship you like.

Comment: Thanks Tico.  Your example of how to set up the models.py file has helped a lot.  I have managed to save the M2M field with todays's date, not a date entered from the form. Is there a way to have the user enter a date in the form for the dateOfDiagnosis field so that this could be saved alongside the diagnosis.  Ideally, I only want this date saved in the 'diagnosisPatient' table and not in the table 'patientData', but this is a nice to have.

Comment: Ok, then I have to tell you something that I'm not particulary proud of: I don't use and have no idea how to use django forms.py. Every time I tried, it didn't do what I wanted it to do, like the case you are having right now...   So everything I do with forms is manual javascript and it is not connected whatsoever with django forms. In short, I have no idea how to bend forms to fit this case! Sry  :|    A quick google got me to this link which looks very helpfull: http://timlwhite.com/2012/07/21/django-many-to-many-model-saving-with-intermediary-through-model/

Comment: I found that link before and played with it, but there appears to be many errors.  If I can't get my models and forms working like I want, I may create separate forms which should achieve, but that would get cumbersome.  In this case I will have to work out how to reference between tables with the ID keys.  (I'm new to this so it will take some time).  Thanks again for the help though.

Comment: Cool. Happy to help! Wish u luck!